# How to enter a multi-word emoji into Pivotal Tracker?

Tags: emoji, pivotal-tracker

Pivotal Tracker currently has a [beta feature](https://www.pivotaltracker.com/help/markdown) which allows the user to enter an emoji. According to their example, you need to enclose the emoji in `:` signs:

[image: Rocket emoji example]

They seem to be using the [Emoji for PHP library](http://code.iamcal.com/php/emoji/) which defines some emoji with multiple words (e.g. `black sun with rays`).

How can I use one of these multi-word emojis in Pivotal Tracker?

Note: Attempting to use `:no entry sign:`, for example, simply outputs the text, rather than the emoji icon.

Answer (score 2):

Some of these can be output by replacing the spaces with underscores (`_`).

For example, `:no_entry_sign:` will work, but `:black_sun_with_rays` will not work.